# ¿Cómo acceder a una posicion concreta de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto

Pues eso, necesito acceder a una posición concreta de un arrayList pero no encuentro como hacerlo.

**tengo esto:**

```
    List<Pedido> pedidos = new ArrayList<>();
```

como veis es una lista de objetos de tipo Pedido y quiero recuperar la fecha del primer pedido es decir del objeto que ocupa la posición 0 del arraylist pedidos..

Comment: Para evitar tener que hacer consultas tan básicas, deberías tener siempre [la API de Java a mano](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/ArrayList.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La interfaz List define un método `get(int index)`, donde index es la posición de la lista a la que quieres acceder y las posiciones, como en los arrays, van de 0 a elementos_en_lista - 1. Por tanto, lo que preguntas se resolvería con

```
pedidos.get(0)
```

Tan simple como eso. Obviamente, deberás controlar si la lista está inicializada, vacía o si tiene, como mínimo, tantos elementos como la posición a la que quieras acceder para evitar excepciones.

Comment: Añadir a la respuesta de @Ivan, que si en la clase donde defines el objeto `Pedido` tienes definido un getter para recuperar la fecha (por ejemplo, `getFecha()`) puedes unirlo a tu `pedidos.get0()` para acceder directamente a la fecha: `pedidos.get(0).getFecha();`